# How to update specific value in a array of JSON values in React, can anyone please explain this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Updating the JSON state using setState is not happening

1.I want to change the particular quantity value in the JSON, for this I wrote an
IncrementHandler method to a  tag and implemented the function but it is not updating my
main state

2.I implemented the setState method inside the function for updating the state.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: 0,
    students: [
      {
        item: 'salad',
        qty: 2,
        department: 'Information Technology',
        rollno: '123'
      },
      {
        item: 'cheese',
        qty: 2,
        department: 'Computer Engineering',
        rollno: '456'
      },
      {
        item: 'meat',
        qty: 2,
        department: 'Information Technology',
        rollno: '789'
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const IncrementHandler = (type) => {
      if (type === 'salad') {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          qty: this.state.students[0].qty + 1
        }));
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <table border="2">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Item</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Button</th>
                </tr>
                {this.state.students.map((item, i) => (
                  <tr key={i}>
                    <td>{item.item}</td>
                    <td>{item.qty}</td>
                    <td onClick={() => IncrementHandler(item.item)}>click</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Naren I Updated the code please have a look

Answer (score 3):

## Issues

You aren't updating the nested state in the `student` array. You are generating a new root state key `qty`.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  qty : this.state.students[0].qty + 1
}))
```

## Solution

Shallow copy the `student` array to create a new array reference, and shallow copy the element you want to update *within* the array. General note about updating nested state in react, you need to shallow copy any object you are updating since React uses shallow object equality to reconcile differences.

```
const IncrementHandler = item => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    students: prevState.students.map(student =>
      student.item === item
        ? {
            ...student,
            qty: student.qty + 1,
          }
        : student,
    ),
  }));
};
```

***Note:** You should probably also declare this callback *outside* the render function.* It will still work defined there in the render method, but it goes against convention.

Comment: Thank You Much !!!! Drew Reese, I learned a thing  !!